# how get sql insert/update query before or after doing a flush() in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to do this:

```
//insert
$entity = new House();
$entity->setName('5 Stars');
$entity->setAddress('Something');
$em->persist($entity);
//or a update
$entity->setName('New Name');
$em->persist($entity);
```

now the function would come

```
$em->flush();
```

I do not know if it would be before or after the flush() and how, but I would like to obtain what would be the query that would be executed to save the data in the database

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you intend to do with that query?

Comment: I want to make a history of the entities and for this I need to obtain the query (Update FROM ..... or INSERT INTO ....)

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple, you need to use Doctrine Lifecycle Events, in your case it is - 'preFlush', 'onFlush', 'postFlush'.

see [Doctrine's Lifecycle Events documentation.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)